# Ratio & Proposition: Question on mixtures

Tags: ratio

Ratio of milk to water in a jar is 5:1. If 10 litres of this mixture is removed and 4 litres of milk and 2 litres of water are added, then quantity of milk becomes 300% more than that of water in the jar. What was the original quantity of water in the jar?

I tried in the following manner and have doubt.

There are three ratios here 5:1, 2:1 (Added 4 litres milk and 2 litres water) and 4:1 (300% more)
If we take LCM, then ratio becomes 25:5, 20:10 and 24:6. If we add the first two ratios then we should get the third ratio right. Whether am I wrong?

Comment: Isn't $300%$ more a $4:1$ ratio?

Comment: Thanks edited the question

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be a quantity of a water in the jar.

Thus, $$5x-\frac{5}{6}\cdot10+4=4\left(x-\frac{1}{6}\cdot10+2\right).$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: Thanks :) This will help in solving the question. In the way I approach, do you want is incorrect?

Comment: @Krishna M Yes. Your mistake is:  $x>0$ greater than $y>0$ on $300$% says $x=4y$ and not $x=3y$.